# flutter run command is stuck

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i download a new project using "flutter create" command, but when i run the flutter run command , it never finished and gets stuck . Below is the log:

> PS C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp> flutter doctor
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.17134.1667], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.2) [√] Android Studio (version 4.0) [√] VS Code (version
> 1.48.1) [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!
>
> PS C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp> flutter run -v [
> +130 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H [  +72 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c
> log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H [        ]
> bbfbf1770cca2da7c82e887e4e4af910034800b6 [   +1 ms] executing:
> [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD [ +271 ms] Exit code 0 from:
> git tag --contains HEAD [        ] 1.20.2 [  +12 ms] executing:
> [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u} [  +42
> ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u} [
> ] origin/stable [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote
> --get-url origin [  +40 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin [   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git [  +87 ms]
> executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD [  +43
> ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD [        ]
> stable [  +56 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not
> required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [
> ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not
> required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [        ]
> Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
> [   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not
> required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [        ]
> Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
> update. [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is
> not required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [
> ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
> skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update. [  +23
> ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> devices -l [  +68 ms] List of devices attached
> 7f287a21               device product:beryllium model:POCO_F1 device:beryllium transport_id:1 [   +9 ms]
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell getprop [ +117 ms] Artifact Instance of
> 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [   +7 ms]
> Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
> skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts'
> is not required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update. [   +4 ms] Artifact
> Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
> [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not
> required, skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [        ]
> Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
> skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update. [
> ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
> skipping update. [        ] Artifact Instance of
> 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update. [ +251
> ms] Generating
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
> [  +63 ms] ro.hardware = qcom [  +72 ms] Starting incremental build...
> [   +3 ms] Initializing file store [  +20 ms] Skipping target:
> gen_localizations [  +23 ms] complete [   +5 ms] Launching
> lib\main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode... [   +7 ms]
> C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
> C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot
> --sdk-root C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/
> --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
> -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.d3293e14\flutter_tool.795dece2\app.dill
> --packages .packages
> -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
> --bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions
> --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill [
> +19 ms] executing: C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump
> xmltree
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
> AndroidManifest.xml [  +79 ms] Exit code 0 from:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump
> xmltree
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
> AndroidManifest.xml [   +1 ms] N:
> android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
> E: manifest (line=2)
> A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
> A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
> A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
> A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
> A: package="com.example.myapp" (Raw: "com.example.myapp")
> A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
> A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
> E: uses-sdk (line=7)
> A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
> A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1c
> E: uses-permission (line=14)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw:
> "android.permission.INTERNET")
> E: application (line=22)
> A: android:label(0x01010001)="myapp" (Raw: "myapp")
> A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw:
> "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
> A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
> A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
> (Raw:
> "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
> E: activity (line=28)
> A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" (Raw:
> "com.example.myapp.MainActivity")
> A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
> A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
> A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
> A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
> E: meta-data (line=42)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
> (Raw:
> "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
> A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
> E: meta-data (line=52)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
> (Raw:
> "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
> A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
> E: intent-filter (line=56)
> E: action (line=57)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw:
> "android.intent.action.MAIN")
> E: category (line=59)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
> "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
> E: meta-data (line=66)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
> A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2 [   +8 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1 [ +279 ms] Exit code 0 from:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell -x logcat -v time-t 1 [        ] --------- beginning of
> main
> 08-25 09:34:24.574 D/MiuiFastConnectService(18094): handleMessage: what: 9, msg.arg1: 0, msg.arg2: 0 [   +1 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1 [ +274 ms] Exit code 0 from:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell -x logcat -v time-t 1 [   +1 ms] --------- beginning of
> main
> 08-25 09:34:25.056 D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(2)( 2345): 4G level = 4 [
> +15 ms] <- compile package:myapp/main.dart [  +16 ms] executing: C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> version [  +80 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
> Version 30.0.4-6686687
> Installed as C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe [
> +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> start-server [  +50 ms] Building APK [  +27 ms] Running Gradle task
> 'assembleDebug'... [   +3 ms] gradle.properties already sets
> `android.enableR8` [   +7 ms] Using gradle from
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\android\gradlew.bat.
> [   +2 ms]
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\android\gradlew.bat
> mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx. [  +12 ms] executing: C:\Program
> Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version [ +389 ms] Exit
> code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> -version [        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode) [   +4 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\android/]
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\android\gradlew.bat
> -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
> -Ptarget=C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\lib\main.dart
> -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
> -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug [+4085 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE [   +1 ms] > Task
> :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE [   +1 ms] > Task
> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task :app:preDebugBuild
> UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE [ +189
> ms] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE [   +5 ms] > Task
> :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE [  +87 ms] > Task
> :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets [   +1 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE [
> ] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:mergeDebugAssets [+1695 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug [
> +1 ms] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE [   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE [  +97 ms] > Task
> :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE [  +99 ms] > Task
> :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE [  +96 ms] > Task
> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE [ +101 ms] > Task
> :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE [   +1 ms] > Task
> :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE [ +197 ms] > Task
> :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE [ +398 ms] > Task
> :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE [   +1 ms] >
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE [        ] > Task
> :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE [  +95 ms] > Task
> :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE [   +1 ms] > Task
> :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE [        ] Compatible side by
> side NDK version was not found. [   +1 ms] > Task :app:packageDebug
> UP-TO-DATE [+1197 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug [   +1 ms] BUILD
> SUCCESSFUL in 8s [   +1 ms] 31 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 27
> up-to-date [ +512 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> (completed in 9.3s) [  +60 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory:
> 'C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'/app.apk
> [  +82 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 81us [ +679 ms]
> calculateSha: computing sha took 679us [ +180 ms] ✓ Built
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. [  +78 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump
> xmltree
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
> AndroidManifest.xml [  +22 ms] Exit code 0 from:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump
> xmltree
> C:\Users\Tufail\Documents\myflutterprojects\myapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
> AndroidManifest.xml [   +1 ms] N:
> android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
> E: manifest (line=2)
> A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
> A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
> A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
> A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
> A: package="com.example.myapp" (Raw: "com.example.myapp")
> A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
> A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
> E: uses-sdk (line=7)
> A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
> A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1c
> E: uses-permission (line=14)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw:
> "android.permission.INTERNET")
> E: application (line=22)
> A: android:label(0x01010001)="myapp" (Raw: "myapp")
> A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw:
> "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
> A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
> A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
> (Raw:
> "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
> E: activity (line=28)
> A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" (Raw:
> "com.example.myapp.MainActivity")
> A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
> A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
> A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
> A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
> E: meta-data (line=42)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
> (Raw:
> "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
> A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
> E: meta-data (line=52)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
> (Raw:
> "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
> A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
> E: intent-filter (line=56)
> E: action (line=57)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw:
> "android.intent.action.MAIN")
> E: category (line=59)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
> "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
> E: meta-data (line=66)
> A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
> A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2 [   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on POCO F1. [   +1 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell am force-stop com.example.myapp [ +161 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell pm list packages com.example.myapp [ +105 ms]
> package:com.example.myapp [ +225 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.myapp.sha1 [  +86
> ms] 8d52b697e19d3cbeb0dc056848c3bb54663b3b70 [   +1 ms] Latest build
> already installed. [        ] POCO F1 startApp [   +3 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000
> --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
> com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity [ +113 ms] Starting:
> Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000
> cmp=com.example.myapp/.MainActivity (has extras) } [   +1 ms] Waiting
> for observatory port to be available... [ +628 ms] Observatory URL on
> device: http://127.0.0.1:37417/9Qbx9A-mVyg=/ [   +2 ms] executing:
> C:\Users\Tufail\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
> 7f287a21 forward tcp:0 tcp:37417 [  +30 ms] 60549 [        ] Forwarded
> host port 60549 to device port 37417 for Observatory [   +7 ms]
> Caching compiled dill [  +31 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:60549/9Qbx9A-mVyg=/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problems in starting your virtual device. Are your virtual device working? Also check that ports not blocked by antivirus or windows defender.

Comment: I am using my phone , and app is starting on it